# Order not found after secure3d

Tags: coinbase-api

I am trying to use the API to buy using my secure3d Mastercard.

Once I have committed the buy using the API, I then redirect the user to the secure3d page using the data returned by the Coinbase API (`secure3d_verification` field). After the user completes the secure3d process it returns to the Coinbase buy confirmation page correctly, but it then fails stating that it can't find the order.

What is the correct process that should be followed when using secure3d?

Thanks!

Comment: As far I was able to discover... Coinbase has a client-side error, they are trying to fetch 'SECURE3D_ACCOUNT_ID' and 'SECURE3D_TRANSFER_DATA' from `localStorage` (which they need to complete the order, because they use that date to call `https://www.coinbase/com/api/v2/accounts/accountId/buys/buyId/complete`), but those items are only set when you do a 3D Secure payment on Coinbase itself, not when you redirect users to Coinbase's 3D Secure redirect page.